# Firefox or Chrome - how to force a specific encoding for a page

Tags: ubuntu, firefox, google-chrome, browser

I am accessing an intranet site built by amateurs, that was constructed to be "best viewed by IE" (arghhh!). The site is in portuguese. All accented letters are jammed and do not appear as they should. As I create sites myself, I know that the best way to build a site in portuguese and other latin languages is to use the  "charset=iso-8859-1" on the page's HTML encoding. This will ensure cross-browser and platforms compatibility.

But I have no way to change this, because I am a visitor on this site.

I don't know the encoding they are using. What I ask is: is there a way I can force my browser (Chrome or Firefox) to recode the page using the correct charset? I need this to work on Ubuntu.

Comment: ISO-8859-1 is absolutely **not** a good encoding — i mean, it doesn’t even have dashes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Firefox click `View->Character Encoding` there you can select quite a few options for the encoding.

Otherwise you could use a greasemonkey script to accomplish this. There are quite a few for various sites on userscript.

Comment: In Chrome, look in the Page menu, Encoding. Both Firefox and Chrome have auto detect settings in their Encoding menus that may help. (But I don't know if the auto detect settings override the character encoding specified in the HTTP response header or the HTML source, or if they only try to auto detect when there's no character encoding specified.)

Answer (score 3):

In Chrome, click on the little file icon (near the top right), and select one of MANY encodings from the Encoding menu.  (Same idea as what was mentioned for Firefox.)

Comment: Clarifying: on the dropdown menu of the browser window (the only menu you got), hover `Tools->Encoding` and then select and encoding.